# How do I see Authentication Header in Google Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, authentication

Title basically says it all. I go to the Network tab and go to the "request headers" but I don't my authentication that is being sent.

[image]

Comment: If the authentication is set correctly, it should appear on Request Headers as "authorization: Bearer your_token"

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

Comment: Looks like this answers your question (Authentication is just a request header): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931720/is-there-a-way-to-modify-an-http-request-in-chrome-or-firefox
tl;dr you can copy the request (curl and a few others) and alter it or use an extension (I have used ModHeader but there are several)